# Can we use directives inside controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, scroll

I have a situation like I have to load infinite number of items to table. These information is coming from API. Currently its showing 10 records. I am trying to implement http://jsfiddle.net/U7Bz9/3126/. In my code ,

```
  <div class="page page-table" id="MainWrap" data-ng controller="Ctrl1" >
  // where all html codes are written
   </div>
```

But in above given link they have not used controller. Controller is not passing to js. How to implement this?

Comment: use the controller in directive

Comment: How to implement that?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/1611/